# View of numpy structured array with offsets

Tags: python, numpy, casting, structured-array

I have the following numpy structured array:

```
In [250]: x
Out[250]: 
array([(22, 2, -1000000000, 2000), (22, 2, 400, 2000),
       (22, 2, 804846, 2000), (44, 2, 800, 4000), (55, 5, 900, 5000),
       (55, 5, 1000, 5000), (55, 5, 8900, 5000), (55, 5, 11400, 5000),
       (33, 3, 14500, 3000), (33, 3, 40550, 3000), (33, 3, 40990, 3000),
       (33, 3, 44400, 3000)], 
      dtype=[('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<i4'), ('f3', '<i4'), ('f4', '<i4')])
```

The array below is a subset (also a view) of the above array:

```
In [251]: fields=['f1','f3']

In [252]: y=x.getfield(np.dtype(
     ...:                    {name: x.dtype.fields[name] for name in fields}
     ...:                    ))

In [253]: y
Out[253]: 
array([(22, -1000000000), (22, 400), (22, 804846), (44, 800), (55, 900),
       (55, 1000), (55, 8900), (55, 11400), (33, 14500), (33, 40550),
       (33, 40990), (33, 44400)], 
      dtype={'names':['f1','f3'], 'formats':['<i4','<i4'], 'offsets':[0,8], 'itemsize':12})
```

I am trying to convert y to a regular numpy array. I want the array to be a view. The issue is that the following gives me an error:

```
In [254]: y.view(('<i4',2))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-254-88440f106a89> in <module>()
----> 1 y.view(('<i4',2))

C:\numpy\core\_internal.pyc in _view_is_safe(oldtype, newtype)
    499 
    500     # raises if there is a problem
--> 501     _check_field_overlap(new_fieldtile, old_fieldtile)
    502 
    503 # Given a string containing a PEP 3118 format specifier,

C:\numpy\core\_internal.pyc in _check_field_overlap(new_fields, old_fields)
    402         old_bytes.update(set(range(off, off+tp.itemsize)))
    403     if new_bytes.difference(old_bytes):
--> 404         raise TypeError("view would access data parent array doesn't own")
    405 
    406     #next check that we do not interpret non-Objects as Objects, and vv

TypeError: view would access data parent array doesn't own
```

However, if i choose consecutive fields it works:

```
In [255]: fields=['f1','f2']
     ...: 
     ...: y=x.getfield(np.dtype(
     ...:                    {name: x.dtype.fields[name] for name in fields}
     ...:                    ))
     ...: 

In [256]: y
Out[256]: 
array([(22, 2), (22, 2), (22, 2), (44, 2), (55, 5), (55, 5), (55, 5),
       (55, 5), (33, 3), (33, 3), (33, 3), (33, 3)], 
      dtype=[('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<i4')])

In [257]: y.view(('<i4',2))
Out[257]: 
array([[22,  2],
       [22,  2],
       [22,  2],
       [44,  2],
       [55,  5],
       [55,  5],
       [55,  5],
       [55,  5],
       [33,  3],
       [33,  3],
       [33,  3],
       [33,  3]])
```

View casting seems to not work when the fields are not contiguous, is there an alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, use the `ndarray` constructor directly:

```
x = np.array([(22, 2, -1000000000, 2000), 
              (22, 2,         400, 2000),
              (22, 2,      804846, 2000), 
              (44, 2,         800, 4000), 
              (55, 5,         900, 5000), 
              (55, 5,        1000, 5000)], 
             dtype=[('f1','i'),('f2','i'),('f3','i'),('f4','i')])

fields = ['f4', 'f1']
shape = x.shape + (len(fields),)
offsets = [x.dtype.fields[name][1] for name in fields]
assert not any(np.diff(offsets, n=2))
strides = x.strides + (offsets[1] - offsets[0],)
y = np.ndarray(shape=shape, dtype='i', buffer=x,
               offset=offsets[0], strides=strides)
print repr(y)
```

Gives:

```
array([[2000,   22],
       [2000,   22],
       [2000,   22],
       [4000,   44],
       [5000,   55],
       [5000,   55]])
```

---

Btw, when all fields in the original array have the same dtype, it's much easier to first create a view on that array followed by a slicing operation. For the same result as above:

```
y = x.view('i').reshape(x.shape + (-1,))[:,-1::-3]
```

Comment: Do the fields have to be continuous for this to work? ['f4','f1'] is still continuous from my understanding. Is that why the assertion is there.

Comment: Try `fields = ['f4', 'f3','f1']`.  offsets are `[12, 8, 0]` - there's a -4 and -8 gap.  `strides` can't handle both.

Comment: @snowleopard Exactly. It always works with 2 fields, but with 3 or more it fails when the offsets are not linearly spaced.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, to expand on what you said, i noticed that it works when accessing the fields triggers basic indexing (that is, slices that have a fixed increment of one or more), and fails when advanced indexing is triggered. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html

Answer (score 1):

The following is a bit confusing - but the gist is that for this kind of `view` to work it has to be able to access the fields with regular array strides and shapes.  Getting a view from ['f1','f3'] fails for basically the same reason that `np.ones((12,4))[:,[0,2]]` produces a copy.

========

In your structured array, each record is stored as 4*'i4' bytes.  That layout is compatible with a (n,4) 'i4' array:

```
In [381]: x.__array_interface__['data']    # databuffer pointer
Out[381]: (160925352, False)
In [382]: x.view(('i',4)).__array_interface__['data']
Out[382]: (160925352, False)          # same buffer
In [387]: x.view(('i',4)).shape
Out[387]: (12, 4)
```

but when I take various slices of this array

```
In [383]: x.view(('i',4))[:,[0,1]].__array_interface__['data']
Out[383]: (169894184, False)       # advance indexing - a copy

In [384]: x.view(('i',4))[:,:2].__array_interface__['data']
Out[384]: (160925352, False)       # same buffer
```

But selecting ['f1','f3'] is equivalent to: `x.view(('i',4))[:,[0,2]]`, another copy.

Or look at the strides.  With the 1st 2 fields

```
In [404]: y2=x.getfield(np.dtype({name: x.dtype.fields[name] for name in ['f1','f2']}))
In [405]: y2.dtype
Out[405]: dtype([('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<i4')])
In [406]: y2.strides
Out[406]: (16,)
In [407]: y2.view(('i',2)).strides
Out[407]: (16, 4)
```

To see this array as just ints, it can step by 16 for rows, and by 4 to step columns and just take 2 columns.

Or look at the full dictionary for the 4 column and 2 column cases

```
In [409]: x.view(('i',4)).__array_interface__
Out[409]: 
{'data': (160925352, False),
 'descr': [('', '<i4')],
 'shape': (12, 4),
 'strides': None,
 'typestr': '<i4',
 'version': 3}
In [410]: y2.view(('i',2)).__array_interface__
Out[410]: 
{'data': (160925352, False),
 'descr': [('', '<i4')],
 'shape': (12, 2),
 'strides': (16, 4),
 'typestr': '<i4',
 'version': 3}
```

same strides and dtype, just different shape.  The `y2` case works because it can access the desired bytes with striding, and ignoring 2 columns.

If I slice out 2 middle columns of the 4 column case, I get a view - same data buffer, but with an offset:

```
In [385]: x.view(('i',4))[:,2:4].__array_interface__['data']
Out[385]: (160925360, False)
```

but using `getfield` with those 2 fields gives the same error as with ['f1','f3']:

```
In [388]: y2=x.getfield(np.dtype({name: x.dtype.fields[name] for name in ['f2','f3']})).view(('i',2))
...
ValueError: new type not compatible with array.
```

`view` can't implement that databuffer offset that slicing can.

========

Looking again at the 2 middle fields:

```
In [412]: y2=x.getfield(np.dtype({name: x.dtype.fields[name] for name in ['f2','f3']}))
     ...:  
In [413]: y2
Out[413]: 
array([(2, -1000000000), (2, 400), (2, 804846), (2, 800), (5, 900),
       (5, 1000), (5, 8900), (5, 11400), (3, 14500), (3, 40550),
       (3, 40990), (3, 44400)], 
      dtype={'names':['f2','f3'], 'formats':['<i4','<i4'], 'offsets':[4,8], 'itemsize':12})
In [414]: y2.__array_interface__['data']
Out[414]: (160925352, False)
```

`y2` is pointing at the original database start.  It achieves the offset with the `dtype` offsets.  Compare that with the offset in `In[385]`.

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer, i was expecting the process to work with continuous fields, but i also noticed that it only works with a slice containing the first field. I do understand that if the fields are not continuous then advanced indexing is triggered which returns a copy. I don't understand why it doesn't work with some continuous fields since that seems to essentially be a slice.

Comment: I added some information on the f2/f3 'slice'.  Both methods require some sort of offset, but they use different methods.  One offsets the databuffer pointer, and uses regular striding from there.  The other uses the `dtype` offsets, and the original databuffer pointer.